# How can a 13 year old kid like me learn quantum mechanics and other advanced physics topics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I have a huge interest in learning quantum mechanics and other advanced physics topics. Also I need to learn the mathematics for physics as well such as linear algebra and calculus. So please could you guys tell me some resources or books which do not dumb down content, but are appropriate for absolute beginners like me. Also may I please get resources or books for QED and QFT, and other advanced physics topics. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. This sort of question is best discussed [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) as the main site is intended for specific questions about concepts in physics. However you need a minimum of 20 rep to use the chat room. If you can manage another 9 rep you'll find lots of people willing to discuss this in the chat.

Comment: Once you learn calculus, the Feynman Lectures on Physics would be a great way to go. All the best! :-) (The Feynman Lectures are made freely available by CalTech: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/)

Comment: In all seriousness the answer is *"start and the beginning and persevere, the same way that everyone else learns it"*. Your age has no appreciable effect on what you have to accomplish, only on what resources are readily available.